# Running Appium/TestNG script on AWS device farm

Tags: appium

When i deploy the zip containing my appium scripts and test.jar (containing all dependency jars used in script) on aws device from run configuration it shows below error-

"could not found test.jar".

Any suggestion what i am missing.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at step 6 in the [instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html), you'll see an example of the expected package structure.

```
Build, package, and verify. For example:

$ mvn clean package –-DskipTests=true
$ tree target
.
|— acme-android-appium-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (this is the JAR containing everything built from the ./src/main directory)
|— acme-android-appium-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar (this is the JAR containing everything built from the ./src/test directory)
|— zip-with-dependencies.zip (this .zip file contains all of the items)
`— dependency-jars  (this is the directory that contains all of your dependencies, built as JAR files)
      |— com.some-dependency.bar-4.1.jar
      |— com.another-dependency.thing-1.0.jar
      |— joda-time-2.7.jar
      |— log4j-1.2.14.jar
      |— (and so on...)
```

The two key areas to look at here are:

- acme-android-appium-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
- acme-android-appium-1.0-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar

Device Farm expects the uploaded package to contain JAR files built from both your `./src/main` and `./src/test` directories. Based on the error message, it is unable to find a `*-tests.jar` file inside of your uploaded package.

My questions for you would be:

- Are you following the `./src/main` and `./src/test` directory structure? Or are you using something different?
- Can you paste the output of the command `mvn clean package --DskipTests=true && tree target`? This should give a clear understanding exactly of what files are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the steps like http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html to create your zip file?

If no, what's the file/folder structure in your zip file?

If yes, could you please mail/PM the url for your failed test run? Then we could take a close look.

Comment: Hi my zip contains all .java files ans a test.jar (containing all required jars) like .zip>.java and test.jar. I have followed the steps and modified pom.xml   but not able to generate .zip as mentioned in link. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Hi , Have you got the chance to look into this problem.

Comment: You don't need to include any java file in the zip since Device Farm will not compile them. And you should have a "dependency-jars" folder in zip file even it's empty. I would still suggest to investigate why your environment failed to generate zip autoamtically based on pom.xml instead of doing this manually. It may save you a lot of time in the future.